# Оптимизационный момент в JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался. С точки зрения оптимизации, если конструктору для создания объекта нужна вспомогательная функция, лучше её сохранить в замыкании или сделать методом конструктора?

```
function Foo() { function func() {} }
```

или

```
function Foo() { }
Foo.func = function() {}
```

или не имеет значения? помимо того, что во втором случае метод будет публичным

Comment: что делает данная функция?

Comment: @Grundy допустим, форматирование данных перед присвоением свойству нового объекта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такие вещи надо просто брать и замерять. По идее, вложенная функция должна быть медленнее, поскольку она создаётся каждый раз при вызове внешней.

В любом случае, весьма маловероятно, что это станет причиной медленной работы скрипта.

```js
function test(f) {
  var t = performance.now();

  for (var q=0; q<1000000; ++q) {
    var x = new f();
  }

  t = performance.now() - t;
  console.log((""+f).match(/function\s+(\w+)/)[1] + "   " + t.toFixed(3) + " ms");
}

function local() {
  function other(a) { a.x = 90; }
  other(this);
}

var closure = (function () {
  function other(a) { a.x = 90; }

  return function closure() {
    other(this);
  }
})();

function field() {
  field.other(this);
}

field.other = function other(a) { a.x = 90; };

test(local);
test(closure);
test(field);
```

PS: У меня в Хроме разница в 5-10 раз против вложенной функции. Но на самом деле это разница не в разы, а на некое число операций, поэтому сравнение на пустых или почти пустых функциях имеет мало смысла.

Comment: в firefox выигрывает локальная функция, с каким-то космическим перевесом. наверное цикл полностью оптимизировался

Comment: @Grundy, Яндекс-браузер - докальная функция проигрывает в 2 раза.

Comment: надо еще в IE/EDGE попробовать :-) local: 84, closure: 44, field: 60

Comment: @Grundy, только что попорбовал. Разница между способами минимальна в Edge - всё от 30 до 50.

Comment: а сафари есть попробовать?

Comment: @Grundy, в 2 раза.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44067/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).